# EPPlus. ActualWidth of column in cm

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

How can I get the column width in cm?
I have already tried a lot of different options, so I ask the question without an example code

Answer (score 1):

Epplus gives the 'character width' of a column in the `.Width` property.

[This source](https://www.translatorscafe.com/unit-converter/en/typography/5-3/character%20(X)-centimeter/) suggests a conversion factor of 0.211666, so we can get the cm width as follows:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var myFileInfo = new FileInfo("input.xlsx");
    using (var excel = new ExcelPackage())
    {
        var worksheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("sheet1");
        var charWidthOfFirstColumn = worksheet.Column(1).Width;
        var widthInCm = charWidthOfFirstColumn * 0.211666;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you are wrong. The width of the columns is not measured in points

Comment: I know it's not measured in points, I wasn't suggesting that in my answer. It's measured in 'character widths' (a ludicrously obscure scale IMHO but I guess they have thier reasons).

Comment: Moreover - today I found out that EPPlus gives out the wrong width values. I had to refuse to use EPPlus and use Interop